# Обрезать PNG с использованием (GDI+) Anti-aliasing

Tags: delphi, изображения, gdi+, crop

Подскажет, как обрезать PNG картинку произвольным методом при помощи GDI+?

Есть рабочий вариант обрезки, но без прозрачности, и с одноцветным фоном, хочется же создать универсальное решение, чтобы на выходе получать прозрачность, где собственно картинка нам не надо, пример:

```
function AACropGDI(const aSrcPic: TPicture; const aRect: TRect; const aPath: IGPGraphicsPath): TPicture;
var
  graphics: IGPGraphics;
  pathPen: IGPPen;
  gpBmp: IGPBitmap;
  vclBmp: TBitmap;
  trColor: TColor;
begin
  vclBmp:= TBitmap.Create;      
  try
    vclBmp.Assign(aSrcPic.Graphic);           // converting to BMP
    Result:= TPicture.Create;                 // creating result object
    Result.Bitmap.Assign(vclBmp);             // copy
    trColor:= clWhite;
    Result.Bitmap.TransparentColor:= trColor;
    pathPen:= TGPPen.Create(TGPColor.CreateFromColorRef(ColorToRGB(Result.Bitmap.TransparentColor)));  // pen
    gpBmp:= TGPBitmap.Create(vclBmp.Handle, vclBmp.Palette);    // GDI+ bmp to draw
    graphics:= TGPGraphics.Create(Result.Bitmap.Canvas.Handle); // GDI+ canvas        //graphics.Clear(TGPColor.CreateFromColorRef(ColorToRGB(Result.Bitmap.TransparentColor))); // clearing by transparent color
    graphics.SmoothingMode:= SmoothingModeAntiAlias; //ANTIALIASED    
    graphics.SetClip(aPath);                  // setting path border
    graphics.DrawImage(gpBmp, TGPRectF.Create(0, 0, aRect.Width, aRect.Height));
    graphics.DrawPath(pathPen, aPath);        // drawing an antialiasied path
  finally
    vclBmp.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  pic, picCroped: TPicture;
  circle: IGPGraphicsPath;
begin
  pic:= TPicture.Create;
  try
    pic.LoadFromFile('D:\image.jpg');
    Image1.Picture.Assign(nil);
    Image1.Picture.Bitmap.SetSize(pic.Width, pic.Height);
    circle:= TGPGraphicsPath.Create(FillModeWinding);
    circle.AddEllipse(TGPRectF.Create(0, 0, Image1.Width - 1, Image1.Height - 1));
    picCroped:= AACropGDI(pic, Rect(0, 0, Image1.Width, Image1.Height), circle);
    Image1.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, picCroped.Graphic);
    Image1.Transparent:= True;
  finally
    pic.Free;
    picCroped.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Проблемы начинаются, когда картинка рисуется поверх другой (есть фон), или должна быть прозрачной. В итоге хочется получить что-то типа:

Исходная картинка:
[image: Исходная картинка]

То, что получется:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]